# JQuery mouseover mouseout function dancing

Tags: jquery, mouseover, mouseout

The following function causes a box to open over a gallery on mouseover. The problem is that it won't stop trying to open and close. This is something to do with the mouseout function being triggered as the mouse moves around the picture.

Dammed infuriating. Any ideas on fixing it?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#gallery, .imageitem, #thumbnails, .thumbs, .cornerimg").mouseover(function(){
     $('#thumbnails').addClass('thumbnailshover');
 });
 $("#gallery").mouseout(function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
           $('#thumbnails').removeClass('thumbnailshover');
        },2000);
 });
});
```

Marvellous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to:

1. use `.hover()` to correctly handle mouse in and mouse out events
2. record the timer handle returned from `setTimeout()`
3. call `clearTimeout()` with that handle at the start of every callback.

See a (simplified) demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/R7v4H/

Answer (score 2):

mouseover and mouseout events may act buggy in many browsers because they trigger when leaving elements inside the element that has the handler. The jquery [mouseenter](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [mouseleave](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) events fix this (see demo at bottom of page).

Comment: Well, that's not really buggy, it's just how events bubble. All events happen, even if there is no handler for it right where it happens. +1 You ar right though that `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` is used to circumvent this.

Comment: I know it's expected behavior, and I should have said "act buggy" (ok, edited out "are buggy") ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the mouseout function to the thumbnailshover class instead of the #thumbnails object. Then it won't be until the mouse leaves the thumbnail that it goes away.

```
$(".thumbnailshover").mouseout(function(){
     setTimeout(function() {
           $('#thumbnails').removeClass('thumbnailshover');
        },2000);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use mouseleave instead. The problem with mouseout is that it is triggered on certain browsers when you mouse over elements inside your container, in this case #gallery.

```
$('#gallery').mouseleave(function(){
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to define `mouseout` on the `#thumbnails` id, instead, and that may just fix your issue.

What's happening is:

Your `mouseover` and `mouseout` events are defined on the same id, `#gallery`, which means when you hover over the `#gallery` the `mouseover` function will be called, BUT because your overlay is now **covering** the `#gallery`, your mouse is no longer "over" the `#gallery`, but it's over the `#thumbnails`, thereby triggering mouseout.